# General classification of degree $d$ homogeneous polynomials in $\mathbb{P}^2(\text{finite field})$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

As the question title suggests, what is the general classification of degree $d$ homogeneous polynomials in $\mathbb{P}^2(\text{finite field})$, up to projective equivalence?

Comment: Classification up to what?

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev classification up to projective equivalence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even over an algebraically closed field, there are some subtleties here. So I assume you're asking about the following action. Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and let $P_d$ be the space of nonzero homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in $k[X,Y,Z]$, modulo the action of $\text{GL}_3(k)$ given by $f\circ L(X,Y,Z)\sim f(X,Y,Z)$. (Or $P_d$ could be polymomials modulo $k^*$ and one could act via $\text{PGL_3}(k)$ or $\text{SL}_3(k)$.) It turns out that the quotient $P_d/\text{GL}_3$ is not very nice. Instead one looks at the semi-stable or stable part of $P_d$, and then there are nice quotients. This is all explained in *Geometric Invariant Theory* (Mumford et al). He works out the 2-variable case ($\mathbb P^1$) in great detail. I don't know a reference for the 3-variable case ($\mathbb P^2$) offhand. Then, once you understand your quotient space over $\overline{\mathbb F}_p$, you can start to study its $\mathbb F_q$ points for finite fields, although there's still the question of whether you are looking at $\text{GL}_3(\overline{\mathbb F_p)}$ equivalence or $\text{GL}_3(\mathbb F_q)$ equivalence.

Comment: is page 46 of these notes relevant?  http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/alg_geom/papers/1977a--StabilityLecturesIHES-Swiss.pdf